# MQ Exception: MQRC_SSL_PEER_NAME_MISMATCH

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I am connecting to MQ message broker via SSL and I sometimes get the exception below. The strange thing is that I am not always having this error and restarting my client process often resolves the issue.

I have already set the SSLPeername when creating the MQConnectionfactory to a value of CN=* but this doesn't seems to resolve the issue. It is also strange to me that it doesn't occur always but only from time to time. Can someone assist me on this ?

thx and kr,

Frederik.

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'UM01' with connection mode '1' and host name 'xxx.xx.net(1449)'.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:585) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.connect(WMQSession.java:392) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.<init>(WMQSession.java:301) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.createSession(WMQConnection.java:884) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.createSession(JmsConnectionImpl.java:594) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsQueueConnectionImpl.createQueueSession(JmsQueueConnectionImpl.java:148) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection.createQueueSession(MQQueueConnection.java:140) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection.createSession(MQQueueConnection.java:162) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at xxxx.server.comm.jms.spring.SingleConnectionFactory.createSession(SingleConnectionFactory.java:521) ~[xxxx.server.comm.jms.jar:na]
    at xxxx.server.comm.jms.spring.CachingConnectionFactory.getSession(CachingConnectionFactory.java:252) ~[xxxx.server.comm.jms.jar:na]
    at xxxx.server.comm.jms.spring.SingleConnectionFactory$SharedConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(SingleConnectionFactory.java:731) ~[xxxx.server.comm.jms.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.createSession(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at xxxx.server.comm.jms.JMSSenderImpl.send(JMSSenderImpl.java:93) ~[xxxx.server.comm.jms.jar:na]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2398' ('MQRC_SSL_PEER_NAME_MISMATCH').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2398;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'xxx.xxx.net(1449)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2398;AMQ9636: SSL distinguished name does not match peer name, channel '?'. [4=CN=xxxxx]],3=xxx.xxx.net(1449),5=RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2050) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1223) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:311) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:337) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.connect(WMQSession.java:348) ~[com.ibm.mqjms.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2398;AMQ9636: SSL distinguished name does not match peer name, channel '?'. [4=CN=xxx]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1219) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:710) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:400) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:299) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:164) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1595) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:7.5.0.1 - p750-001-130308]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Here is the code I use to make a connection:

```
            final MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
            factory.setChannel(this.jmsConfig.getChannel());
            factory.setHostName(this.jmsConfig.getHostname());
            factory.setPort(this.jmsConfig.getPort());
            factory.setQueueManager(this.jmsConfig.getQueuemanager());
            factory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);

            String sslPeerName = this.jmsConfig.getSslPeerName();
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(sslPeerName))
            {
                logger.info("Setting SSL Peername: {} ", sslPeerName);
                factory.setSSLPeerName(sslPeerName);
            }

            String sslCipherSuite = this.jmsConfig.getSslCipherSuite();
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(sslCipherSuite))
            {
                logger.info("Setting SSL Cipher Suite: {} ", sslCipherSuite);
                factory.setSSLCipherSuite(sslCipherSuite);
            }
            connection = factory.createConnection();
```

The exception happens during a createSession

```
con.createSession(transacted, ackMode);
```

Comment: Please add the error message seen in the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG file at the same time as the MQRC_SSL_PEER_NAME_MISMATCH is seen in your client application. I expect that there is an SSLPEER defined at the queue manager name (either in the channel or with CHLAUTH) and it is that which is catching you out.

Comment: What I find very strange is that I didn't define a sslpeername on client side and what I understand from the specs is that in this case the check should not be done. So why is this error being thrown in the first place. Also the fact that it doesn't occur always is something I cannot explain.

Comment: Are you saying that there is nothing in the queue manager error log?

Comment: Also, perhaps post your code to go along with the error you have posted?

Comment: Hello, I have updated the question with some code fragments.

Comment: Have you checked the queue manager `AMQERR01.LOG` as @MoragHughs mentioned above?  Does it report an error at the same time?  Does  `this.jmsConfig.getHostname()` always return the same value?  If it does, does that value point to a DNS or IP loadbalancer?

Comment: Didn't get any feedback from our MQ managers about the AMQERR01.LOG file. For the moment I am suspecting an issue in the MQ libs. I have updated from 7.5.0.1 to 7.5.0.7. Since the issue is very irregular, I'll have to wait a few days to see if it still occurs.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I am having the same problem